# Postman GET Response binary

Tags: rest, api, postman, postman-mocks

I am setting up a mock server and would like to have a GET Response containing an image file, I cannot find any information on how to set this up.

The response section of Postman only has - Pretty/Raw/Preview options and no - from-data/binary?

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to add the image to a Mock Server example with an `<img>` [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) and add the `text/html` *Content-Type* header.

You can either reference the URL or [base64 encode the image](https://www.base64-image.de/) and use the value within the tag. The base64 value of the image is going to be *massive* though.

[image: Mock Image]

Comment: Hi Danny, thanks for shedding a light on the matter. I had the same thought initially that I am talking over HTTP and I should be getting and sending out text based messages, however, there is a Postman directory in - `C:\Users\<username>\Postman\files` - where one would store files. So I figured the mock server also have some basic storage capabilities and I do not need to convert the image into base64 value. With that being said, I am processing this endpoint as `Stream` and the stream still has 0 bytes length. Ultimately I would need Postman to host an image file, is this possible?

Comment: I guess the only way it's going to _host_ it, is if you put that base64 value into a variable, that's synced to your Postman account. The working directory is related to something different, not the mock servers.

Comment: escaped ASCII ? http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/ascii.php - No idea :)